# Keys.PageDown.ToString() returns Next

Tags: c#

I've read a few articles on this issue. Basically PageDown and PageUp are linked to Next and Prior respectively, for backwards compatibility. The problem with this is there's no reliable way to get the wanted values out (atleast none that I can see).

See [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/2ae9bab3-46d6-482b-a220-409d1b3f1cfb/string-representation-of-keys-enum) for a good explanation. Quite old though, I thought something might have been done to address this by now.

At present there are two options I can see;

1. `Enum.GetNames(typeof (Keys)).GetValue(e.KeyValue);`

This returns "Prior" for "PageUp" but "PageDown" for "PageDown".

1. `e.KeyCode.ToString();`

This returns "PageUp" for "PageUp" but "Next for "PageDown".

I could handle it manually, but what if there's another instance like this?
Does anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the best thing to do is to create a lookup table to translate the enum values.

You could implement the lookup table with a dictionary to map the enum values onto strings, and if the dictionary doesn't contain the enum value fall back to Enum.ToString() to get the value. That way you only need to add the exceptions (such as PageUp and PageDown) to the dictionary.

(Note that if you are displaying these strings to the user and you want to internationalize the strings you will probably need to add translated entries for most of the strings.)

Comment: Yeah, I've resorted to handling it manually like this. Pity there's not a better option.